# как передать атрибуты ссылки другой ссылки

Tags: html, reactjs, link, href

допустим ссылка на мой сайт https://my-syte/?id=1
и у меня есть кнопка на сайте, которая ведёт на другую страницу/сайт
задача передать атрибут ?id=1
чтобы ссылка с кнопки была https://button-href/?id=1
соответственно атрибуты могут быть абсолютно разные
использую react, если это важно

код самого компонента:

```
import bgDesk from '../../assets/mainBlock/bg.png'
import bgMob from '../../assets/mainBlock/MobBg.png'
import { useRef } from 'react';

const MainBlock = (props)=>{
    let bg = bgDesk;

    if(window.innerWidth > 1024) {
        bg = bgDesk;
    } else {
        bg = bgMob;
    }
    return(
        <section className={s.mainBlock}>
            <div className={s.container + ' ' + 'container'}>
                <h1 className={s.heading}> <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: props.texts.heading}}></div></h1>
                <p className={s.subHeading}> <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: props.texts.text}}></div></p> 
                <a href={props.texts.href} target='_blank' className={s.button + ' tryForFree'}>{props.texts.button}</a>
            </div>
            <img src={bg} alt="" className={s.Bg} />
            <img src={props.img} alt="" className={s.img} />
        </section>
    )
}

export default MainBlock;
```

Comment: Взять и перенести. Для более детального ответа нужен ваш код, что бы было видно, как что формируется, где эта ссылка, что за кнопка и так далее

Comment: в коде это обычная ссылка 
тэг <a>
грубо говоря блок с ссылкой, которая значения href из пропсов принимает, но добавить к ней атрибуты - не сложно, мне интересно как эти атрибуты достать из ссылки

Comment: Можно конечно useRef попробовать, однако проще и правильнее из тех же пропсов взять нужные атрибуты и запихнуть их кнопке

Comment: а как их получить в более высокий файл?
эти атрибуты не я пишу, с этими атрибутами юзер переходит на сайт. то есть внешняя ссылка изначально с этими атрибутами
у меня ссылка для кнопки вообще из редюсера идёт. Можно ли в редюсер js получить ссылку целиком или, желательно, только атрибуты?
для управления общим стейтом использую redux, если это важно

Comment: Я же говорю - покажите код. Все можно придумать

Comment: код кроме компонента нужен?

Comment: Ну как достать данные понятно. А кнопка где? В компоненте выше?

Comment: кнопка - это ссылка <a> с href={props.texts.href}. Вот в неё мне нужно добавить параметры текущей ссылки. То есть поместить параметры в переменную и передать их через + ссылке

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться стандартным свойством **window.location**

Достаточно взять параметр search, удалить первый символ(?) и добавить в нужное место

```
<a 
    href={`${props.texts.href}&${location.search.substring(1)}`} 
    target='_blank' 
    className={s.button + ' tryForFree'}
>
    {props.texts.button}
</a>
```

Если есть вероятность, что в props.texts.href может не быт get параметров, тогда придется добавить проверку

Полученный props превращаем в URL и проверяем get параметры

```
const urlLink = new URL(props.texts.href);
let sep = '&';
if (!urlLink.search) sep = '?';
```

И меняем рендер так:

```
<a 
    href={`${props.texts.href}${sep}${location.search.substring(1)}`} 
    target='_blank' 
    className={s.button + ' tryForFree'}
>
    {props.texts.button}
</a>
```